# passing to MVC Control parameter from Javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, fullcalendar

In my jQuery code I am calling a controller action and I'm trying to pass in dates from the fullcalendar plugin:

```
url: ('Home/List/?dateValueStart=' +  new Date($('#calendar').fullCalendar('getView').start))
+ '&dateValueEnd=' + new Date($('#calendar').fullCalendar('getView').end),
```

In my controller I have my method setup like this:

```
public ActionResult List(String dateValueStart, String dateValueEnd)
```

When I debug dateValueStart I see this:

```
Tue Oct 1 00:00:00 MDT 2013

DateTime dateVal = Convert.ToDateTime(dateValueStart);
```

But when I try to convert this to a date it tells me it is invalid.

> String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

How can I get a date close to 10/1/2013?

Comment: Where's your code to parse the string to a `DateTime`?

Comment: @JasonP in C# or javascript?  I don't have either as none of it really worked...

Comment: Have you tried [`DateTime.Parse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1k1skd40.aspx)?

Comment: @JasonP Yeah I looked at that, but that gave me virtually the same message.  I updated my question with what I was originally trying.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript date support isn't the greatest.  There are shorter ways to do the following but they don't work in all browsers:

```
var formatDate = function(d){
    var curr_date = d.getDate();
    var curr_month = d.getMonth() + 1; //Months are zero based
    var curr_year = d.getFullYear();
    return curr_month + "/" + curr_date + "/" + curr_year;
}

var startDate = new Date($('#calendar').fullCalendar('getView').start);
var endDate = new Date($('#calendar').fullCalendar('getView').end);

var url = 'Home/List/?dateValueStart=' + formatDate(startDate) + '&dateValueEnd=' +
formatDate(endDate)
```

Also, check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056728/formatting-a-date-in-javascript)

Comment: I really wanted that to work but I got an invalid date when I implemented this.

Comment: Oops!  British date format has the month and day reversed.  I've edited the above to get it right.